# How to restore system default settings in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: unity, menu, system-settings, unity-control-center

I am trying to restore the unity control center but there are always missing items even after I run:

```
sudo apt install unity-control-center
```

and

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

You can see some items are missing, like Language support, Security & privacy, Additional drivers, Printing, Backups, Software updates

Comment: For starters ck & see if the `activity-log-manager` package is installed. If  it's not then  install it & the Security & Privacy panel should return. If that's the case then the rest of the missing can be returned by finding the missing packages.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to restore Ubuntu from live CD. Download the iso and reinstall Ubuntu. It is the fastest and best way to fix your problem. Othrewise you can run `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and `sudo apt install unity`. After these commands you might need to run `unity` on a terminal